# Android epub reader development approaching

Tags: epub, solution, ebook-reader

I am writing a proposal for epub reader project which have ability to display vertical text for Japanese language. Firstly, I want to know the main flow of a book reader to load and read epub then define the key point / main technology need to focus on the proposal.

The requirement of book reader here is to have basic features: read book, display current/total pages, go to any position of the book.

As I understand the main flow as bellow:

1. The BReader extract the epub to xhtml files
2. The BReader load all the xhtml files to webview
3. The BR add the js to rotate text to vertical. The js can be [nehan](https://code.google.com/p/nehan/)
4. The BR add the js to separate the pages base on the device screen specification
5. Render the current page

However, in step (2), if it load all the xhtml files, the performance will be very poor for large epub. I studied some Epub Reader like as "E-bookreader of SONY" and "NeoSoar" and see that the time of open a epub is the same (around 5 seconds) for every epub files so I believe that they only load a part of the book at the first time.

How can they do that? and if they only load a part of the epub how do they calculate the total pages? and how they can go to any page number of the book?

Answer (score 1):

You Probably need to refer [this](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android).

Download epublib-core-latest.jar from [github](https://github.com/downloads/psiegman/epublib/epublib-core-latest.jar)
Download slf4j-android
Add both to your android project

and follow the sample.

Comment: thanks for your support. I used these libraries for my project already but my concern is how to handle the large epub file

Comment: @All : I referred your suggested solution. but I got error `"java.lang.exceptionininitializererror"`.. What is this error? How to solve it? Thanks in advance..